# Move file to new location created based on filename batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have few file that need to be organize by month into new folder that created by the filename that contain string & number.

example file :

`Cycle2006_P.zip
 Cycle2307_P.zip
 Cycle2410_P.zip`

Result:

`Jun\Cycle2006_P.zip
 Jul\Cycle2307_P.zip
 Oct\Cycle2410_P.zip`

Here what I tried. But the result are different. The script only capture Cycle2410_P.zip and create Oct folder only.

Result :

`Oct\Cycle2006_P.zip
    \Cycle2307_P.zip
    \Cycle2410_P.zip`

```
@echo off

Set filename=D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\pbilsr01\*.zip*
For %%A in ("%filename%") do (
    Set Folder=%%~dpA
    Set Name=%%~nxA
)

REM get the 7th string from filename and set into %month% e.g. 06 = Jun
set month=%Name:~7,2%


if %month%==01 set currentmonthfolder=Jan
if %month%==02 set currentmonthfolder=Feb
if %month%==03 set currentmonthfolder=Mar
if %month%==04 set currentmonthfolder=Apr
if %month%==05 set currentmonthfolder=May
if %month%==06 set currentmonthfolder=Jun
if %month%==07 set currentmonthfolder=Jul
if %month%==08 set currentmonthfolder=Aug
if %month%==09 set currentmonthfolder=Sep
if %month%==10 set currentmonthfolder=Oct
if %month%==11 set currentmonthfolder=Nov
if %month%==12 set currentmonthfolder=Dec

:Move
@echo off
echo.
echo Move File to New Location
mkdir "D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\Backup\%currentmonthfolder%"
Move "D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\pbilsr01\*.zip*" "D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\Backup\%currentmonthfolder%" 

set RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo.
  echo Success Move
  GOTO Copi
) else (
  echo Error. Retry. . . .
  TIMEOUT /T 5 >nul
  GOTO Move
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off

SETLOCAL
:AGAIN
SET "NAME="

Set filename=D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\pbilsr01\*.zip*
For %%A in ("%filename%") do (
    Set Folder=%%~dpA
    Set Name=%%~nxA
)

IF NOT DEFINED NAME ECHO No files found&GOTO COPI

REM get the 7th string from filename and set into %month% e.g. 06 = Jun
set month=%Name:~7,2%


if %month%==01 set currentmonthfolder=Jan
if %month%==02 set currentmonthfolder=Feb
if %month%==03 set currentmonthfolder=Mar
if %month%==04 set currentmonthfolder=Apr
if %month%==05 set currentmonthfolder=May
if %month%==06 set currentmonthfolder=Jun
if %month%==07 set currentmonthfolder=Jul
if %month%==08 set currentmonthfolder=Aug
if %month%==09 set currentmonthfolder=Sep
if %month%==10 set currentmonthfolder=Oct
if %month%==11 set currentmonthfolder=Nov
if %month%==12 set currentmonthfolder=Dec

:Move
@echo off
echo.
echo Move File to New Location
mkdir "D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\Backup\%currentmonthfolder%"

REM    Move "D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\pbilsr01\*.zip*" "D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\Backup\%currentmonthfolder%" 
Move "D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\pbilsr01\%FOLDER%%NAME%" "D:\Users\AALADELA\Desktop\Backup\%currentmonthfolder%" 


set RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo.
  echo Success Move

  REM      GOTO Copi
  GOTO AGAIN

) else (
  echo Error. Retry. . . .
  TIMEOUT /T 5 >nul
  GOTO Move
)
pause
```

I've tried to fix your routine - modifications in ALL-CAPS. Your code `REM`med out if replaced.

Changes:

1. Add `SETLOCAL` to discard environment changes when routine finishes.
2. Setting `name` to *nothing* allows test after `for` to indicate whether a matching file was found
3. Detect whether a file was found. Message and go to `COPI` if not.
4. Move the ONE file to new location - note name reconstructed from `%FOLDER%` and `%NAME%`.
5. On success, go to `AGAIN`, not `COPI` to process next file.

Comment: Thanks @magoo. this what i need. I just need to remove `%FOLDER%` from `Move` since the location already stated or use `Move %FOLDER%\%NAME%` , everything work.